# Micronaut application: NoSuchMethodError in a Groovy record

Tags: json, groovy, micronaut

I have a Micronaut 4 Groovy application. The app tries to serialize records with the serde serialization library. The app is a Groovy clone of a Java app in the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0O1WckQeew

The app fails with
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String jsonserde.Book.getTitle()'`

I use the recommended Micronaut libs:

```
annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor")
implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")
```

The record is annotation with `@Serdeable`

```
package jsonserde

import io.micronaut.serde.annotation.Serdeable

@Serdeable
record Book(String title) {

}
```

The controller returns a list of book objects.

```
package jsonserde

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get

@Controller
class BookController {

    @Get('/books')
    List<Book> index() {

        return [new Book('War and peace'),
                new Book('Father Goriot'),
                new Book('Call of the Wild')] as List<Book>
    }
}
```

What causes the error?

It's a bug and is [reported](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/9667)

Comment: do you have somewhere in code calling `Book.getTitle()` ?

Comment: No. It's just these two files and the Application class that launches the application.

Comment: not clear why it should work. `record` is not creating getters and setters...